# Codeigniter - 404 Page Not Found error

Tags: codeigniter

codeigniter working on my local machine but not on server.

```
administrator/application

administrator/system

administrator/assest
```

I tried some `.htaccess` files but codeigniter not working.

Comment: paste your code in `.htaccess`

Comment: what errors do you get? are you still having issues?

Answer (score 1):

On codeigniter 3 Check all your controller and model make sure the **filename and class name** have there **first letter** as uppercase example Welcome.php and class Welcome

Also if you have not configured your index.php to be removed on either codeigniter 2 or 3 versions then you will need to add in url each time you use a link.

Live Server URL Example

> http://www.example.com/index.php/site

Localhost URL Example

> http://localhost/project-name/index.php/site

Some Htaccess Example Link

[How to remove index.php codeigniter 2 & 3](https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter)

Comment: thank you so much, controller name lowercase change uppercase